# Sound stopped working on Toshiba Satelite C855

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, troubleshooting, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satallite C855 running Windows 7 with a Realtek High Definition Audio card.

Sound worked fine yesterday. Today, my two-year old did something to the machine, and I have no sound.

I have adjusted sound through the icon in the lower right corner, and using the Fn keys. I have rebooted. I've verified that there are no external speakers plugged in to the laptop.

It seems that this model does not have an external volume control. (If it does I can't find it.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a fair bit to check, but to go through some that I know:

1. First test is to check if sound is still working. Play a music / video in the background, LEFT click on the Sound Icon, and choose Mixer. You will get a window showing the speaker volume on the left hand side, and various application that are using sound at the moment. If you see some green bar going up and down based on your Video/Movie/youtube/etc, then we need to check other things
2. Right click on the Sound Icon (bottom right corner) and choose Playback devices, and make sure the correct speaker (the one currently have green bar going up and down) is set as "Default Device" and to be safe (for testing) "Default Communication Device"
3. If you can't see your speaker listed there maybe the sound driver somehow got uninstalled - check under Device Manager (Right Click on "My Computer" and choose Manage)
4. I saw a picture of the Toshiba keyboard and there is an Fn key to mute/unmute. It should only be a software mute, but that is another one you can test.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks much, but no luck. All of these check out fine, but no sound.